# Qt: open context menu on mouse press

Tags: c++, qt4, contextmenu

I'm trying to change the default behavior of context menus: Instead of opening on the release event of the right mouse button, I want it to open on the press event, and it's actions to be triggered on the release event). On one widget I could overload the `mousePressEvent()` and fire a custom contextmenu event, but I want it to be global to all the context menus of my program...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want one menu to be fired-up on mouse button release form any of you widget or you want every widget to have its own menu (like it is) but change the default behavior of them ?

Comment: I want every context menu of my application to be triggered on mouse press event (given it's the behavior of applications on Mac OS X, I thought there were a flag or an option to set for other platforms).

Comment: As a side comment, won't this break the habits of the users of the other operating systems ? I really dislike applications that don't behave properly in their environment, it really breaks the user experience.

Comment: For a widely distributed software, I totally agree. In that case it was a specific request from the users, who were used to that behavior in the previous versions of the software we were redeveloping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to implement a widget base on top of `QWidget` with a custom way to handle context menu to suit your needs when I realize that using `ActionsContextMenu` policy with actions directly own by the widget does exactly the behavior you are expecting. (Qt 4.6.2 & 4.7 on linux, didn't try on windows yet but I don't know why the behavior should be different).

Is that a policy you can use ? If you don't *really* need external menus, I'll suggest to go with this solution.

Otherwise you will have to create your own widget base with a custom `QMenu` member. You should use the `Qt::PreventContextMenu` policy to guarantee the right click to end in the `void    mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` of your widget. In this event handler make sure to show your menu. In your menu re-implement the `void mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent *event)` if it don't trigger the current action do it your-self with the mouse position (in the event) and the `QAction* actionAt( const QPoint & pt) const`. But be careful the `void mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent *event)` of the `QMenu` is already re-implemented from `QWidget` and may do some stuff you want to preserve !

---

**EDIT**
It's kind of sad but this behavior seems to be different *by design* on windows the `void QMenu::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)` does the following:

Extracted form `qmenu.cpp`, Qt 4.6.2 sdk

```
#if defined(Q_WS_WIN)
        //On Windows only context menus can be activated with the right button
        if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton || d->topCausedWidget() == 0)
#endif
            d->activateAction(action, QAction::Trigger);
```

I don't know what the `topCausedWidget()` does in life but it's kind of explicit that only left button release will trigger the current action ...

One simple solution for you will be to re-implement your `QMenu` with this line commented ...

Comment: Using the context menu policy `Qt::ActionsContextMenu` just changes the  `QAction`s used in the menu, not the display behavior of the menu itself. BTW I'm using Qt 4.5 on Windows.

Comment: Ok didn't try all policies, just saying with the announced configuration I got the exact behavior your are expecting ... don't know if it's linux/mac specific though, but if it comes out of the box with 4.6 and later, updating your Qt could be a good thing to consider, isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that's not my call to upgrade to a newer version. I'm gonna try with 4.7, and if it works, I'll strongly suggest an upgrade to the client. Thanks. (I'll mark your answer as accepted if there's no best answer within a few days).

Comment: After checking it seems that the behavior comes from the OS, not the Qt version.

Comment: Right, but the issue is not to trigger the action (doing it on release is fine for me), it's to pop the context menu up on press.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to create your own class based on `QMenu`, and use it for every context menu in your program.

Check [here](http://www.qtforum.org/article/27835/custom-qmenu.html) for a reference.

Comment: If it's the only way, sounds like I'm not gonna like it... ;)